# Is there a correct way to override a javascript function in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am detecting popups on a site by overriding window.open with a closure of itself with some additional logic.

```
const PopupWarning = () => {
  const [failedUrl, setFailedUrl] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [showPopupWarning, setShowPopupWarning] = useState<boolean>(false)

  window.open = function (open) {
    return function (url, name, features) {
      name = name || 'default_window_name'
      const popup = open.call(window, url, name, features)
      try {
        popup.focus()
        setShowPopupWarning(false)
        setFailedUrl(null)
      } catch (e) {
        setFailedUrl(url.toString())
        setShowPopupWarning(true)
      }
      return popup
    }
  }(window.open)
...
```

Is this an acceptable way to do something like this? It works during all of my tests, but I wonder if this code should be in a useCallback or other.

I tried searching for this idea and couldn't find much. I bet overriding window.open is frowned upon, but it's the best solution for this use case (can't change source html). Thanks!

Comment: I agree that overriding built-in behavior is generally a bad idea. What problem are you trying to solve? You want to alert people to the fact that another window was opened programmatically? And your React app is being rendered into a page you don't otherwise control?

Comment: Probably the main improvement this needs is that you'll want to do this in `useEffect` also restore the original `window.open` when your component unmounts.

Comment: @ray Yeah the app loads predefined HTML that can't be changed and that utilizes window.open in buttons. I need to warn the user if they have pop-ups blocked.

Comment: Given the constraints your solution seems pretty reasonable. Are the buttons that open the popups easily identifiable? Do you have visibility into how they launch the popups? If so you might be able to monkeypatch their event handler or something instead of window.open, but I’m not sure that would necessarily be better than what you have.

Comment: I feel like the way react would want you to do it is to define a function that implements your open logic then pass that down with a Context Provider. Then the components wouldn't be directly calling `window.open` at all, just your wrapper function and no monkey patching required but I'm not sure how applicable that is if your pages are mainly static html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the window.open proxy on component mount, and uninstall it on unmount. You can use useEffect hook to achieve this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const originalOpen = window.open;
    window.open = function (url, name, features) { // install proxy
        name = name || 'default_window_name'
        const popup = open.call(window, url, name, features)
        try {
            popup.focus()
            setShowPopupWarning(false)
            setFailedUrl(null)
        } catch (e) {
            setFailedUrl(url.toString())
            setShowPopupWarning(true)
        }
        return popup;
    };

    return () => {
        window.open = originalOpen; // uninstall proxy
    };
});
```